# What does “single spread” mean?

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

Recently I read an article about the Windows Phone design. The author kept mentioning the term *spread*, as in "single spread" and "long spread of content". I thought they would be explained later on in the article, so I read on, but tough luck. He just kept using it. So I stopped reading, confused.

Here's a part of the article demonstrating the use of the term in context:

> Even though Panoramas are made out of panels or sections, we should design them as single long spreads of content. Think of one of those two, three or even four page spreads in magazines. The ones that unfold, sometimes being the cover itself, and others being pages within the magazine for an advertisement or poster. By designing the Panorama as a single spread and not in chunks you will be able to sell the immersive experience that Panoramas offer in a much more compelling manner to users.

What does *spread* mean here? What is "a single spread", what are "four page spreads"?

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary?

Comment: Here it's referring to a *single* (one) panorama picture *spread* over *4 pages* of a magazine (presumably with the pages folded over within themselves to allow them to be extra wide). It's the normal meaning of *spread*!

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spread#Noun: "An item in a newspaper or magazine that occupies more than one column or page."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *magazine spread* referred to in the quote corresponds to *spread* as it appears in the definition of *[double-page spread](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/double-page-spread)* at cambridge.org:

> In a book, magazine, etc. a double(-page) spread is one article, set of photographs, etc. that covers two pages opposite each other.

That is, a *spread* is what you see when a magazine has been opened and spread out.  The  three- or four-page spreads referred to in the quote arise when oversize sheets are bound into the magazine; a page may fold out once along one edge for a three-page spread, or facing pages may each fold out once for a four-page spread, or pages may  fold out more than once, etc.

Just how this applies to  Windows Phone design isn't clear to me, although the rest of the article may spell that out.  Perhaps it is suggesting use of single long webpages or display pages rather than breaking an article up into several shorter pages.

*Edit:* Per StoneyB's comment, here's [an example](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_szY6czURhx0/TRKReFUJY7I/AAAAAAAADcY/d8Fn8_1nv8w/s1600/Pacer4PageSpread.jpg) of a four-page spread, where facing pages each fold out once:
[image]

Comment: [**Here**](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_szY6czURhx0/TRKReFUJY7I/AAAAAAAADcY/d8Fn8_1nv8w/s1600/Pacer4PageSpread.jpg)'s an example.

Comment: In context, it means laying out the app content very similarly to what's seen in the example you provide. Windows Phone content is typically laid out to scroll horizontally, like a magazine spread, rather than vertically like most websites and most mobile phone apps.